# Problem with space in to_string after read_sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

On my app (hosted on ubuntu), i am calling a sql request on a sql server.

Ex :

```
query="SELECT col1, col2 FROM shop ;"
shop_list = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

then

```
shop = "test"
shop_info=shop_list.loc[shop_list["col1"]==shop]
val1 = shop_info["col1"].to_string(index=False)
```

On my ubuntu, no problem, I get :

```
val1 : "abcd"
```

But on my windows (I don't know if it is the reason), I get :

```
val1 : " abcd"
```

with a space at the beginning

Is it normal ?

Is there another way to get this value on both environments without the space ?

Thanks a lot.

Jerome

Comment: Can you try `shop_info.head()` on both systems and see whether the space exists for `col1`?

Comment: I see no difference between print(shop_info) and print(shop_info.head()). The print is formated and value is right aligned

Comment: done !! shop_info["col1"].values[0] - works like a charm !

Comment: It is advised against using `values` whether on `Dataframe` or on `Series`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html. Also, you can post your own answer and accept it after 2 days.